# How do you setState outside of component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to decouple the event handler state change logic from `React Component A` and put it inside `class B`. `class B` (so not a React component) should be able to change state of `component A`.

So I don't want to pass function reference `setState(B.handle)` to setState but be able to `setState` from `class B`.

How to do it?

Is passing `this` to constructor of class B the way to go?

edit: sorry, forgot to mention that i can't use third party libraries to keep it dependencies free.

Comment: why would you not use the function passing to `setState`? It's definitely the way to do it.

Comment: @WilomGfx it's a lot of logic (library) and the component will get messy.

Comment: in this case, use a state engine like redux to lift your state up

Answer (score 3):

The usual way to set state from another component, is through a state engine like redux. When a state gets changed, if multiple components are watching the state, it can update each component that cares about that slice of the application state.

In the latest versions of React, they introduced [contexts](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/replacing-redux-with-the-new-react-context-api-8f5d01a00e8c), which provide similar functionality.

Comment: OP mentions that Component B is not a react component

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Redux provides a [`.dispatch()`](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatch) action that can dispatch an action manually.

Answer (score 2):

I think we can use refs: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  .... // Somewhere
  this.myRef.setState(newState);
  ...
  render() {
   return <ChildComponent ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

To make changes to the props: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation